# Lowercase i accent problem

Tags: accents, uppercase

I am having a trouble with author names.

```
\author[A]{\fnms{Melih}}
```

produces

[image]

I need a dot on top of "I", as written in the code. However, "\.i" does not work. Is there any way to create as below

[image]

but with lowercase letters? ("\.I" works well)

Comment: Please tell us (a) how or where `\fnms` is defined and (b) which fonts or font packages you employ.

Comment: I apologize, those are coming from the template of Annals of Probability but I am not familiar enough to answer your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the commands you show in your code fragment are standard definitions so it is very hard to comment on your example but using base latex definitions (Some setups for Turkish may change this)

uppercase of i is I but uppercase of dot accent on dotless i gives you the dot accent on I

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{Melih} \MakeUppercase{Mel\.{\i}h} \MakeUppercase{Mel\.{ı}h}

\textsc{Melih}  \textsc{Mel\.{\relax i}h} \textsc{Mel\.{ı}h}

\end{document}
```

(Note using `\.\i`  in `\textsc` is the same as using `i` so produces I, however adding `\relax` prevents the letter being recognised and so the dot accent is preserved, or you can directly use the UTF-8 dotless i `ı`)

Comment: This works with the class used by Annals of Probability; on the other hand, if the same class is used with the option `bj` (Bernoulli) the output will be funny (due to the class/package using `\uppercase` instead of `\MakeUppercase`).

Comment: @egreg ah you found the class:-) well I think using uppercase would be a class bug so the fix there would be to patch it to use MakeUppercase (or an expl3 case changer)

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you can accept `\sc` in a LaTeX document, then
`\textsc{Mel}\.{\sc ih}` does the work.

A bit longer purely LaTeX solution may be `\textsc{Mel}\.{\scshape ih}`.

Comment: +1. `\textsc{Mel\.{\scshape i}h}` works too.

Comment: +1. I randomly figured out Mel\.{\.i}h also works. Is there anything wrong with using it?

Comment: @Atbey Please do not remove the comment with `Mel\.{\.i}h `. It looks like a side-effect, but really interesting.